# QuickFIXJ MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance wrong argument type

Tags: java, jmx, quickfix, mbeans, quickfixj

While building the JMX Client service for QFJ, I encountered errors when using different MBean interfaces. I need to invoke the methods in ConnectorAdminMBean but it cannot be bound to SessionAdminMBean's method. The error thrown:

```
newProxyInstance() in MBeanServerInvocationHandler cannot be applied to: 
interfaceClass: (Expected) java.lang.Class<T> | (Actual) ConnectorAdminMBean.class
```

The method:

```
public static <T> T newProxyInstance(MBeanServerConnection connection,
                                         ObjectName objectName,
                                         Class<T> interfaceClass,
                                         boolean notificationBroadcaster) {
        return JMX.newMBeanProxy(connection, objectName, interfaceClass, notificationBroadcaster);
    }
```

This has confirmed to work:

```
ObjectName mBeanBLBG = new ObjectName("org.quickfixj:type=Session,beginString=FIX.4.2,senderCompID=SCB,targetCompID=BLBG");
SessionAdminMBean mBeanBLBGProxy = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(jmxConnectionInstance.getmBeanServerConnection(), mBeanBLBG, SessionAdminMBean.class, true);
```

However when I tried to do this, it throws an error of 3rd argument being wrong:

```
ObjectName mBeanConnector = new ObjectName("org.quickfixj:type=Connector,role=Initiator,id=1");
SessionAdminMBean mBeanConnectorProxy = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(jmxConnectionInstance.getmBeanServerConnection(), mBeanConnector, ConnectorAdminMBean.class, true);
```

I have looked into the respective interfaces but fail to see any difference.

```
package org.quickfixj.jmx.mbean.session;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import quickfix.SessionNotFound;
public interface SessionAdminMBean {
    String getBeginString();
    String getTargetCompID();
    String getTargetSubID();
    ...
```

Compared with:

```
package org.quickfixj.jmx.mbean.connector;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.management.openmbean.TabularData;
public interface ConnectorAdminMBean {
    String getRole() throws IOException;
    void stop(boolean var1) throws IOException;
    void stop() throws IOException;
    TabularData getSessions() throws IOException;
    String getHostName() throws IOException;
    int getQueueSize();
}
```

Please advise on what could be the reason that interface ConnectorAdminMbean cannot be bound to Class<\T>. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved by matching the argument class to the MBean proxy class, i.e. by changing:

```
SessionAdminMBean mBeanConnectorProxy = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(jmxConnectionInstance.getmBeanServerConnection(), mBeanConnector, ConnectorAdminMBean.class, true);
```

to

```
ConnectorAdminMBean mBeanConnectorProxy = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(jmxConnectionInstance.getmBeanServerConnection(), mBeanConnector, ConnectorAdminMBean.class, true);
```